# PLSQL Procedure to insert employee: ORA-00984

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, sql-insert

I am trying to insert employee data into employee table from hr database using procedure. I'm getting these errors:

```
19/5 PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
20/72 PL/SQL: ORA-00984: column not allowed here
```

when I execute this code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc_add_new_emp(p_employee_id         IN NUMBER,
                                         p_employee_first_name     IN VARCHAR2,
                                         p_employee_last_name      IN VARCHAR2,
                                         p_employee_email          IN VARCHAR2,
                                         p_employee_phone_number   IN VARCHAR2,
                                         p_employee_hire_date      IN DATE,
                                         p_employee_job_id         IN VARCHAR2,
                                         p_employee_salary         IN NUMBER,
                                         p_employee_commission_pct IN NUMBER,
                                         p_employee_manager_id     IN VARCHAR2,
                                         p_employee_department_id  IN VARCHAR2) IS
BEGIN    
INSERT INTO employees (employee_id, employee_first_name, employee_last_name, emp_email, employee_phone_number, employee_hire_date, employee_salary, employee_commission_pct, employee_manager_id, employee_department_id) 
VALUES(p_employee_id, p_employee_first_name, p_employee_last_name, p_emp_email, p_employee_phone_number, p_employee_hire_date, p_employee_salary, p_employee_commission_pct, p_employee_manager_id, p_employee_department_id);          
END;
/
```

Comment: The error identifies lines 19 and 20. The code you show has only 16.

Comment: Wrong parameter name is usd. just replace `p_emp_email` with `p_employee_email` within the `VALUES` list. There seems no other error presumably the clumn names are true.

Comment: I already updated p_employee_email parameters, i got another error says 14/204    PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "EMPLOYEE_DEPARTMENT_ID": invalid identifier

Comment: then, there should be no column named `employee_department_id` within the table

Answer (score 0):

This is the cause of the error:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc_add_new_emp(
    p_employee_id IN NUMBER, 
    p_employee_first_name IN VARCHAR2,
    p_employee_last_name IN VARCHAR2,
    p_employee_email IN VARCHAR2,         --> this  
  
INSERT INTO employees 
  (employee_id, 
   employee_first_name, 
   employee_last_name, 
   emp_email, 
   ...)
VALUES
  (p_employee_id, 
   p_employee_first_name, 
   p_employee_last_name, 
   p_emp_email,                         --> and this
```

If parameter's name is `P_EMPLOYEE_EMAIL`, then you have to use *it* in `INSERT` statement, not `P_EMP_MAIL`.

Comment: I already updated the p_employee parameters, i got a new error.  It says 14/204    PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "EMPLOYEE_DEPARTMENT_ID": invalid identifier

Comment: So don't use column names that don't exist in the target table. I can't help any better as you didn't post table's description.

Comment: here's the table description
Name           Null?    Type         
-------------- -------- ------------ 
EMPLOYEE_ID    NOT NULL NUMBER(6)    
FIRST_NAME     VARCHAR2(20) 
LAST_NAME      NOT NULL VARCHAR2(25) 
EMAIL                NOT NULL VARCHAR2(25) 
PHONE_NUMBER            VARCHAR2(20) 
HIRE_DATE         NOT NULL DATE         
JOB_ID               NOT NULL VARCHAR2(10) 
SALARY              NUMBER(8,2)  
COMMISSION_PCT          NUMBER(2,2)  
MANAGER_ID              NUMBER(6)    
DEPARTMENT_ID           NUMBER(4)

Comment: It appears that column name is DEPARTMENT_ID. Names are listed in the - who'd guess - **NAME** column of the table description output.

Comment: Looks like the column name in the procedure is not existing in the table, one way to identify this type of error is to run the SQL used in the stored procedure , in SQL plus / Tpad /SQL developer and find the columns which are not existing in the table